# Do Windows Console Virtual Terminal Sequences provide a way of scrolling the screen buffer?

Tags: windows, cmd, terminal, ansi-escape, vt100

The Viewport Positioning mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences#viewport-positioning) for some reason doesn't work like for example scrolling a terminal window with a mouse wheel does.

I expected the Virtual Terminal Sequences in question to move lines that previously were outside the viewport into the viewport and move lines that previously were inside the viewport out of the viewport. Instead, it deletes the lines from the buffer I expected to be moved out and inserts new lines where I expected the previously not displayed lines to appear.

Is there a way to perform the same action as scrolling with the mouse wheel would but with Virtual Terminal Sequences? [SetConsoleWindowInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolewindowinfo) provides this functionality but I want to stick to Virtual Terminal Sequences if possible.

Another way of achieving my goal would be to set the cursor position to coordinates outside of the current viewport. The VTS for [Cursor Positioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences#cursor-positioning) however work only within the current viewport. [SetConsoleCursorPosition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolecursorposition) provides this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't do that.   As noted at the top of [*Console Virtual Terminal Sequences*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences#viewport-positioning)

> The behavior of the following sequences is based on the VT100 and derived terminal emulator technologies, most specifically the xterm terminal emulator. More information about terminal sequences can be found at http://vt100.net and at http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html.

The virtual terminal's viewport is like the visible screen of an xterm. Control sequences update that viewport, but (ignoring old data being scrolled ***out*** of the viewport) do not update the viewport from data ***outside*** the viewport.

The control sequences related to the mouse only are used for enabling mouse events (button-clicks, select/paste), and do not cause the viewport to move around.

Comment: Yet Microsoft is shifting away from the original Console API (SetConsoleCursorPosition, ...). Am I missing something here? Wouldn't this mean that there will be no way to programmatically scroll a console window?

Comment: Some of *Console API* is supported by Windows Terminal (not the mouse part, but perhaps the viewport manipulation).